# When resizing a leaflet map how can I keep the map centered?

Tags: leaflet

I'm using [leaftlet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) to create a map on a web page.

On the left hand side of the map is a panel that slides out.

When the panel slides out the map is resized to fill the remaining space on the page.

As the panel slides out to the left map resizes the centre point moves to the left.

Ideally the centre point of the map should remain in the relative centre.

Dodgy ASCII representation:
(The '.' represents the initial centre point of the map.)

```
Panel closed:          [][    .    ]

Panel open (current):  [  ][     . ]

Panel open (desired):  [  ][   .   ]
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwbLg/4/) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: what about having the panel slide on top of the map?  (so that no re-centering/re-drawing/etc is necessary)

Comment: Then it covers the map controls for zooming and what not. I have considered moving it to the right hand side and letting it slide over the map, but I'd prefer it to work as intended.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this, as any time I resized a map, the center stayed in the center. That said, using a resize event handler might work: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-resize

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle with a reproduction of the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this by calling <strike>`$(window).resize()`</strike> after the leaflet map size changes

Update: Looks like you need to call `map.invalidateSize()` instead

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YwbLg/11/ (animation isn't pretty)

Comment: I've checked the updated fiddle link in both Chrome and IE, and the issue still remains. The center of the map before expanding the panel is not the center of the map after expanding the panel.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm not sure why the fiddle doesn't work. If you resize the window after opening the panel you can see it is related to the map needing to repaint as the map does jump back to being centered.

Comment: Looks like you can call `map.invalidateSize()` after the animation completes

Comment: What if do what to tell leaflet that the size of the  map has changed but I don't want to keep the center ? that animation is pretty ugly

Comment: @AlexandruC in newer Leaflet versions you can use `map.invalidateSize({pan: false})`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSFiddle, if you Inspect Element (right click option on Chrome) on the DIV that holds the map, #map-containerDiv, you'll see that when the options DIV, #mapOptions, slides right, the map div is actually pushed to the right and not resized.

In other words, the center point of the map is not actually changing.
The map div is just sliding to the right, and the right side of the div becomes hidden.