# Resizing a leaflet map on container resize

Tags: javascript, resize, leaflet

I have a `<div>` containing a leaflet map. Upon certain events the height of the `<div>` will be altered. I'd like for the map to resize to the new dimensions of its surrounding `<div>` so that the old center is centered in the resized smaller or larger map. I tried using the `invalidateSize()` function, but it doesn't seem to work at all. How can I resize and center the map after that `map-container-resize` event?

```
$mapContainer.on('map-container-resize', function () {
   map.invalidateSize(); // doesn't seem to do anything
});
```

*Edit to give more context:*

The map container is styled initially as

```
#map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

After a user clicks a certain button, another panel shows at the bottom of the page and the map-container's height will be reduced to something less than 100% (say 80%).

Upon click on this button, the map-container-resize event is triggered so that I can make the map resize and center on its old (i.e. before the resizing happened) center. The map itself should then also be resized to 80% of its initial height.

The APi doc for `invalidateSize` seemed to be what I wanted:

> "Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so
>   [...]"

But having a look with the output of the `getSize` function before and after the call to invalidateSize, nothing is different, the map remains at its old size.

Comment: This needs more context. Are you actually firing a `map-container-resize` event? How is the map sized in CSS?

Comment: did you mean 'resize' event ? this one works

Comment: `on('resize')` only applies to WINDOW resizing, and `map-container-resize` does not exist. so what was the actual event here?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The problem is that the resizing of the `#map-container` `div` is done via a css transition. The transition hasn't started yet, let alone ended, when the call to invalidateSize happens so the leaflet map cannot recognize any change of dimensions of its surrounding `div`.

Triggering the `map-container-resize` event with a delay solved the problem. This way :

```
setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize()}, 400);
```

Comment: working example: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787856/2471632](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787856/2471632)

Comment: A better solution might be to listen for [the `transitionend` event](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=JavaScript&docset_name=JavaScript&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event.html&platform=javascript&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event).

Answer (score 26):

I came across this question today and wanted to provide an updated answer based on 2020 Browser API. This example uses the Browser's [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to monitor the size of the div that Leaflet is mounted too.  Assuming the following HTML Snippet:

```
<div id="map" />
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
const map = L.map(mapDiv).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  map.invalidateSize();
});

resizeObserver.observe(mapDiv);
```

This should monitor the map div, and call the invalidateSize() method on the Leaflet map when the map div size changes. This approach allows you to handle the resizing "closer" to the map code, rather than trying to rely on window resize events or listening for changes triggered elsewhere in the application.

Obviously the CSS for the map div itself will need to ensure that it resizes in whatever way you want it to. This code snippet will ensure the Leaflet is appropriately updated when that happens.

Comment: this answer was Very helpful with some edition on angular 8 or above
  const resizeObserver = new (window as any).ResizeObserver(() => {
            map.invalidateSize();
  });
   resizeObserver.observe(mapDiv);

Comment: perfect answer! saved me a huge headache! Leaflet centering seems good even I transition it's size with grid columns.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me as well! I had Leaflet in a flex container containing the map and a toolbar. Before this fix, the leaflet center would be totally off whenever the toolbar changed size. Now it correctly stays centered! Thanks for this

Answer (score 20):

`L.Map.invalidateSize()` only informs leaflet map object that its container size has been changed, and therefore is should draw less or more map tiles. It does not actually change any dimensions, e.g. of its containing `<div>`, and does not move the map. You should do it yourself.

Comment: This should be the best answer ! Thanks

Comment: It does move the map

Answer (score 13):

You can use below code after **resize** that

```js
map.invalidateSize()
```

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/690

Answer (score 8):

Just **call resize window event** rather than timing the map to load.

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));  


// Triggers a window resize 
// Thus your map automatically triggers invalidateSize().
```

Comment: This solution is really clean and is working great for me so far, are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: Yes. Say in future if you want to detect real window resize events at the main application level. Above process will create one false signal. That is during it’s time of initiation or depending on how many times you are calling the above process.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem using ionic 7 inside a tab component

Answer (score 6):

the accepted answer is a bit hacky in that it relies on the sleep being longer than the transition.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914760/how-to-listen-to-the-end-of-a-bootstrap-animation) to work well:

```
$("body").on($.support.transition.end, '#main-navbar .nav-collapse', function(event){    
    console.log("end of the animation");
});
```

Comment: Note that [`jQuery.support` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem running VueJS, Leaflet 1.2.0. The resizing didn't appear complete as others mentioned above. My solution within VueJS was to call the nextTick function:

```
  var vm = this
  var container = vm.$refs.container
  vm.mapStyle.width = `${vm.getElementContentWidth(container)}px`
  vm.mapStyle.height = `${vm.getElementContentHeight(container)}px`
  vm.$nextTick(() => {
    if (vm.map) vm.map.invalidateSize()
    if (vm.layerBase) vm.layerBase.redraw()
  })
```

I believe pure javascript would be

Comment: Thanks the nextTick with invalidateSize solved my issue !

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this in 2023 with `mapbox-gl` (v1.13.x) and `Vue` (v2.7), the answer is similar. I put this code in the `mounted()` handler:

```
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.map.resize(); // instead of invalidateSize, new API
    // make sure we are zoomed correctly
    // this.boundingBox is a computed property
    this.map.fitBounds(this.boundingBox);
  });
});
resizeObserver.observe(this.$refs.mapContainer);
```

Comment: how do i keep the map centered on a group of markers as the container changes size (enlarged in my case)? btw, the markers are variables so i cant hard code any coordinates

Comment: @oldboy - you'd have to make sure the bounding box is computed correctly, but the `fitBounds` should keep it centered if so!

Comment: can u point me to something that shows how to correctly compute the bounding box given 2 random markers?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the best way, but I did it like this:

```const bounds = bbox(features)
const southWest = new mapboxgl.LngLat(bounds[0], bounds[1]);
const northEast = new mapboxgl.LngLat(bounds[2], bounds[3]);
return new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast);```

where `features` is an array of geojson feature objects

Comment: hm... the thing is, i dont know the locations/geocoords of one set. (there are two sets, from which a location from each set will be paired with a location from the other set; one set is completely unknown aka user geocoords). and if u set the bounding box like that, wouldnt u have to adjust/update it when, say, even the device orientation changes?

Comment: Hm - it seems confusing - how can you _plot_ a marker without knowing the location in the first place? If it's user input, when the user inputs the location, then you can find the coords and resize the bounding box upon getting that input using a function like that above.

Comment: the browser will know the coords if the user decides to share them, but theyre unknown until then, whereas the other set is known

Comment: Sure - so, when the buyer shares the coordinates, then you can resize the box by adding those features that the buyer shared to the 'features' object in my code above. That should do it AFAICT.