# How to set map height dynamically in angular 5

Tags: angular

I created a project to use a Leaflet map. The project has navbar and a sidebar. The sidebar's height is higher than the map. When the map loads how can I give dynamic height to the sidebar and the map? Example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-project)

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. What does it mean give dynamic height to the map and the sidebar? Can you explain?

Comment: The map and the sidebar must be fit on the screen. The scroll must not be appear

Comment: Therefore, you want to resize the map container so that a scrollbar does not appear depending on the screen size. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to resize the map and the sidebar when page load and window resize.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412325/resizing-a-leaflet-map-on-container-resize) as a starting point. I am not sure how to achieve this behavior regarding the map right now. I will take a look later when I find some time.

Comment: Thanks.  Before I used that method on AngularJS but it is Angular 5. If I give a height to the container it will solve.