# Leaflet map not loading fully. At begining it load properly,but when I want open with large height and width it wont working only half of tiles loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is the result that I got partially loaded map remaining part id gray color pary:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: After resize call map.invalidateSize().
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836942/8283938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strong text**
http://codrate.com/questions/how-can-trigger-the-window-resize-event-manually-in-javascript

its working now maps all tiles loaded