# Using React Leaflet with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-lazy-load

I am using React Leaflet. React and everything is working fine, but when I try to use React lazy loading the map just not render or render a small square as shown below. It is just a small box.

[image]

```
<MapContainer center={[selectedLat, selectedLong]} zoom={zoom}>
 <ChangeView center={[selectedLat, selectedLong]} zoom={zoom} />
  <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a 
   href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'  
   url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
</MapContainer>
```

Also, I added the CSS in `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
  crossorigin="" />
```

Comment: Please add your lazy code!

Comment: And what happens when you resize your window?

Comment: Agree with @ghybs, solution is almost certainly triggering a window resize. This is a known issue with certain situations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412325/resizing-a-leaflet-map-on-container-resize

Comment: when I resize the window it works fine and load all the data.